# How to test Jupyter notebooks on Travis CI?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, jupyter-notebook, ipython, travis-ci

Is there a way to deploy Jupyter Notebooks on Travis CI and test running all the cells?

My Jupyter Notebooks use IPython Kernel, and I have a conda environment file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been wondering something similar and have compiled some information but haven't fully tested it yet.

Firstly, you can rely on `jupyter nbconvert` execute notebooks, where you can then look for errors. There's an example set up with Travis CI and Conda at [ghego/travis_anaconda_jupyter](https://github.com/ghego/travis_anaconda_jupyter). I believe Travis CI relies on [`pytest`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest) too to catch issues, though I'm not entirely sure how this fits together.

Another way you can run this is with [`pytest-notebook`](https://github.com/chrisjsewell/pytest-notebook), which relies on you having a working version of the notebooks you want in some environment. This package's main purpose is to detect if changes to the environment will create issues within the notebooks. This can also potentially be used in conjunction with the above method, though it might be redundant.

It might be additionally beneficial for version management (tracking, seeing diffs, legibility) to write your notebooks in markdown format and then use [`jupytext`](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext) to convert them into a `.ipynb` file to then run with the above options. `jupytext` can also execute notebooks directly with the `--execute` flag, so perhaps there's an even simpler way to integrate such a workflow!

I will be testing this in the coming weeks and will update this comment if I learn anything new.

Comment: Hi, Jason! Are there any news about the task?

Comment: Hi @Mikhail_Sam! To be honest, I don't think I'll get to this until February, so please don't wait for me on it – perhaps see the example I linked to above. The main thing I haven't figured out yet (or given much thought to) is what types of errors are important to note in a CI build. Are all errors important or can some be allowed? I'm leaning more to the former...

Comment: I have a solution wit `nbconvert` which locally works fine yet on travis it does not find kernel, I have no idea what kernels are on travis: `jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named python3`